# How to use "easymp3gain-qt"?

Tags: wine, mp3, audio-recording

I installed "easymp3gain-qt 0.5.0+svn135-6" from the Ubuntu Software Center and... it does nothing!

I mean: the main program interface is opened, but... when I ask it the expected action (to normalize the volume of some mp3 audio file), the program stops and asks me: "Is mp3gain installed?"

I tried to install mp3gain, but it is only to Windows and it doesn't run with Wine!

So... How can I use this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble, only with the gtk version.  Turns out that in some repos (I tried Lubuntu and Synaptic), only the GUI front-end is available, without the actual subprograms, i.e., mp3gain, vorbisgain and aacgain.  Going to the mp3gain site, as you found out, is useless since you'll only find Windows binaries.  From another post [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772217/all-songs-at-the-same-volume-in-audacious/772443#772443), it was apparent the .debs for mp3gain could be found (in various architectures) at the following link:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mp3gain/

I downloaded from this archive and installed using gdebi and it worked for me.

Comment: I download another similar app (GUI mode) called "mp3 Diags" and another apps (only in command line mode) called "normalize-audio" and "normalize-mp3". We can use them together and... IT WORKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have installed only `mp3gain` frontend. To use it, it is necessary to install `mp3gain` package. Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install mp3gain
```

Now run `easymp3` again and it must be ok now.

Comment: `mp3gain` is not available from repositories from 14.10 onwards. The latest version can be obtained from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mp3gain/1.5.2-r2-6).