# all songs at the same volume in audacious

Tags: xubuntu, mp3, volume-control, audacious, wma

Is there a plugin in Audacious that plays all the songs at the same volume?

I think this tool is what I am looking for, but it looks like a dead project:
http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/

I mostly have mp3 songs, and a few wma songs as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:**
use mp3gain and easymp3gain.

**Explanation:**

After some research, I have come to understand that the volume normalization can be independent from the music player you use.

You have two types of normalization:

- one normalization on the fly, must be integrated in the audio player
- another one that replaces the original file with a new file with a reajusted volume. It is irreversible but doesn't ask extra performance to your CPU while playing the song.

I have chosen the second normalization. I use mp3gain, even though it's old, it still works.

Install gdebi to install **mp3gain**:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Then download the deb file of mp3gain:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mp3gain/mp3gain_1.5.2-r2-6_amd64.deb
Right click on it and install it with gdebi.

Now let's use mp3gain with a nice gui, **easymp3gain**:
http://www.ihaveapc.com/2011/01/how-to-install-and-use-mp3gain-in-linux-mint-ubuntu/

You may choose apply album gain or track gain. To understand what they mean read this:
http://forums.ilounge.com/ipod-classic-legacy-ipods/246610-track-album-gain-using-mp3gain.html#post1328914

I have tested easymp3gain, seems to work for me: after applying the gain, I can play the songs in Audacious and all have the same volume :).

I am on xubuntu 16.04